# Divergent integral after changing variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

I was working on finding the volume of the intersection of two cylinders
$$
  x^2 + y^2 = a^2 \quad \text{and} \quad y^2 + z^2 = a^2.
$$
I am well aware of the volume being $16a^3/3$ and I know how to compute it.

However, when I compute it using polar coordinates, the following happens:
$$
\begin{align*}
        &\phantom{{}={}}\int ^{2\pi} _{0} {
            \int ^{a} _{0} {
                \sqrt{a^2 - r^2 \sin^2 \theta} \, r
            } \, dr
        } \, d\theta  \\
        &=
        -\frac{1}{2} \int ^{2\pi} _{0} {
            \int ^{a^2 \cos ^2 \theta} _{0} { 
            u ^{1/2}  \cdot 
            \frac{r}{r \sin ^2 \theta}
            } \, du
        } \, d\theta  \tag{$u = a^2 - r^2 \sin ^2 \theta$} \\
        &=
        -\frac{1}{2} \int ^{2\pi} _{0} {
            \frac{1}{\sin ^2 \theta}
                \left[ \frac{2}{3} u^\frac{3}{2} \right] ^{a^2 \cos ^2 \theta} _{a^2} 
            }
        \, d\theta \\
        &=
        -\frac{a^3}{3} \int ^{2\pi} _{0} {
            \frac{\cos^3 \theta - 1}{\sin ^2 \theta}
            }
        \, d\theta \\
        &=
        -\frac{a^3}{3} \int ^{2\pi} _{0} {
                \frac{\cos \theta (1 - \sin ^2 \theta)}{\sin ^2 \theta} 
                - \csc ^2 \theta
            }
        \, d\theta \\
        &=
        -\frac{a^3}{3} \int ^{2\pi} _{0} {
                \cot \theta \csc \theta - \cos \theta
                - \csc ^2 \theta
            }
        \, d\theta \\
        &= - \frac{a^3}{3} \left[
            -\csc \theta - \sin \theta + \cot \theta
        \right] ^{2\pi} _0.
\end{align*}
$$

The integration domain of $\theta$ includes $\pi$, which
$$
-\csc \theta - \sin \theta + \cot \theta
$$
diverges. Despite this, one can get the correct value by excluding $\pi$ in the integration.

My question is that **I do not understand what the change of variable makes the integral divergent**. Geometrically, the volume is bounded by the cylinder so it could not be divergent. A possible reason I can think of is that by letting $u = a^2 - r^2 \sin \theta$, the area element becomes $\csc^2 \theta$, which is very large when $\theta$ is small. However, this does not answer why there is only a discontinuity at $\theta = \pi$, not $\theta = 0$.

Please contribute if you have any thought. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I didn't check the computation, but in the result the difference $\cot \theta - \csc \theta = (\cos \theta -1)/\sin\theta$ 'cancels' the poles of their parts at $\theta=0,2\pi$, because then $\cos \theta = 1$. Hence the enumerator is of order $\theta^2$ and the denominator of order $\theta$ around $0$, giving a finite value in the limit (it's even $0$). For $\theta=\pi$ that cosine is however $-1$, so the difference is indeed a pole.

Comment: I'm also wondering why, for an integration supposedly leading to a volume, there are only 2 integrals and 2 variables, $\theta$ and $r$. Cylindrical coordinates need a third coordinate, IMO.

Comment: @Ingix to answer your question, the integral w.r.t. $z$ had already been completed which is where the integrand of the computation comes in, and why it is non unity.

Comment: @Ingix I said this integral gives a a volume since it is the integral of the nonnegative part of a function over a domain. It should give a volume bounded above by the function and below by the $x-y$ plane over the integration domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you made the mistake of assuming $\sqrt{x^2} = x$. The correct simplification after plugging in your bounds should have been $$(a^2\cos^2\theta)^{\frac{3}{2}} = a^3 \left|\cos\theta\right|^3$$ You can check that for this version of the integrand $$\lim_{\theta\to n\pi}\frac{1-\left|\cos\theta\right|^3}{\sin^2\theta} = \lim_{\theta\to n\pi}\frac{1-|\cos\theta|}{(\theta-n\pi)^2}\cdot\frac{(\theta-n\pi)^2}{\sin^2\theta}\cdot\left(1+|\cos\theta|+\cos^2\theta\right) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 \cdot 3 = \frac{3}{2}$$ i.e. the singularities in the integrand are nonexistent.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I indeed did not consider the negative branch of the root. This also explains why the integral over $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ works as $\cos \theta$ is nonnegative there.